# How Can i Connect to remote MySql Server

Tags: java, mysql

I need to connect MySql Database using Java. The IP :178.63.144.17 port :3306.I can access the Database using PhpMyAdmin via http://178.63.144.17/phpmyadmin/ URL.

Give me a solution

Comment: "Give me a solution" is the wrong tone for this site. What Java code have you already tried to make the DB connection? 5 minutes with Google should get you pretty far if you haven't written any code yet.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, I would recommend checking out [Java Database Connectivity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) (JDBC). This is a Java API that allows your Java application to interact with a data source, such as a relational database like MySQL.

To use JDBC, you will need a MySQL driver which can be downloaded from the MySQL webpage. It is called [Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: I tried to connect Using SqlYog . But failed..

Comment: I am not sure what that is, but I recommend you follow the link I provided. It contains a simple example which you can utilize to get your application quickly connecting to and querying a MySQL DB.

Comment: How are you trying to connect ? Providing your existing code will help others to help you.

Comment: con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://178.63.144.17:3306/myDb", "******", "***********");

Comment: If you *edit* your question and add the code below your original content and then use the code button, then it will be in courier and easy for everyone to peruse.

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception ?

Comment: yes.. The error is: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at connectserver.DBManager.openConnection(DBManager.java:79)

Comment: The error must be that the MySQL server is configured to listen only to requests on localhost. Try connecting to that mysql from your machine using mysql command line client.  Try `mysql -u <username> -p -h 178.63.144.17` and give the password when prompted and see whether it is connecting

Comment: I got the mistake. the MySql was configured as Local. I chnaged. Thank you for help.